# Dropdown visible to false in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a menu navigation bar with drop down menu in asp.net project.i have done this with jquery.To get into this page i have 5 hyperlinks in previous page. when i click on one of the hyperlink and enter the navigation bar page,i need to make dropdown visible to false. i dont have any idea related to this.Suggest me a idea to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you just want to hide an element. But your post isn't particularly clear.

---

To hide something you have a few options..

On the server (page load or similar):

Setting `myList.Visible = false;` will mean the control is not rendered on the client side. Alternatively you can set `myList.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";` or `myList.Style["display"] = "none";`.

On the client (jquery):

You can call `$('#myList').hide();` to hide it.